# How to make Laravel routes strict?

Tags: laravel

I have route in the Laravel:

```
Route::get('/mypath','OnePagesController@somePage');
```

I have also commented out lines in .htaccess to prevent Apache HTTP server redirecting from:

`https://example.com/mypath/` to `https://example.com/mypath`

But now I have a problem. Laravel accepts any of the following paths:

1. `https://example.com/mypath`
2. `https://example.com/mypath/`
3. `https://example.com/mypath//`

How to write routes, that only `https://example.com/mypath` would be a valid route, and all other returned 404 - not found error?

Note: Apache .htaccess is not an option for me.

Comment: A trailing slash typically indicates a directory, not a resource. You're kind of going against conventions with adding it, and there is no benefit, so why do you want/need to do this? What will it provide you besides an extra character in the url?

Comment: @MrEduar - I don't want to add a slash. I want that Laravel responds to exact path I have specified.

Answer (score 0):

This [package](https://github.com/illuminatech/url-trailing-slash) allows enforcing URL routes with or without trailing slash. You can decide per each route, whether its URL should have a trailing slash or not, simply adding or removing slash symbol ('/') in particular route definition.

In case URL for particular route is specified with the trailing slash - it will be enforced for this route, and request without slash in the URL ending will cause 301 redirection. In case URL for particular route is specified without the trailing slash - its absence will be enforced for this route, and request containing slash in the URL end will cause 301 redirection.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('items/', ItemController::class.'@index')->name('items.index'); // enforce trailing slash
Route::get('items/{item}', ItemController::class.'@show')->name('items.show'); // enforce no trailing slash

// ...

echo route('items.index'); // outputs: 'http://example.com/items/'
echo route('items.show', [1]); // outputs: 'http://example.com/items/1'
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing that package to my attention. I was hoping to achieve it without modifying Laravel source, and I need that URLs with slash yield 404 not 301.